# Where condition in a LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ query expressions that use a **lambda expression**. I have one method by which I want to update the value in a different table.
It is working fine in single or default, but not when I use a Where condition.

```
public static void UpdateData(int UserID)
{
    using (var objEntity = new DataContext())
    {

        UserMaster objUser = objEntity.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID);
        UserOfferUsed objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds.Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID);
        objUser.Purchaseon = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM  yyyy");
        objUserUsed.UsedCoupon = 0;
        objEntity.SaveChanges();
        objData = null;
    }
}
```

> Error :Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'Database.UserOfferUsed'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Answer (score 4):

`.Where` will return an `IQueryable` here, use `.SingleOrDefault` or `.FirstOrDefault` to get the result(if the required result is only a single item). or you can use `.ToList()` if the result will contains more than one element. If so you have to change `objUserUsed` as `List<UserOfferUsed>` That is, Your code will be Like this:

```
UserOfferUsed objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds.FirstOrDefault(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID);
```

Or Like this

```
List<UserOfferUsed> objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds.Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID).ToList();
```

You can choose one of the above according to your requirement;

**Update:** If the `UserID` is unique for each element in the list then `.FirstOrDefault()` will be the best option since the query will not give more than one result( you have to consider `null` too, Since `FirstOrDefault()` will give null if there is no specified match found). If you Go with the List and you want to update those values means you can do like the following:

```
foreach(var objUserUsed in objEntity.UserOfferUseds.Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID))
{
   objUserUsed.UsedCoupon = 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you For your quick response. but after i get list how can i update in objUserUsed table's column value ? Because i need to update more than onew value in table.. not only single or first..

Comment: Instead of this `objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds.Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID).FirstOrDefault()`; we could try this `objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds.FirstOrDefault(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID);`

Answer (score 1):

A linq statement acts on sequences that are enumerable. This means that you can say: give me the first one. and: I've got this one, give me the next one.

Most linq operators return an IEnumerable < T >, meaning, it returns another sequence. The sequence is not enumerated until you perform something like foreach or until you perform a linq statement that doesn't return en IEnumerable < T > but a T

In other words: as long as your statements return sequences the code is not really enumerated.

If you look up SingleOrDefault, you'll see that the return value is a T. To calculate the return value the sequence is enumerated.

The return value of Enumerable.Where is not a T, but IEnumerable < T >. The compiler says so.

To get the same result as your first statement you'll need the parameterless SingleOrDefault:

```
IEnumerable<UserOfferUsed> mySequence = objEntity.UserOfferUseds
    .Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID);
UserOfferUsed objUserUsed = mySequence.SingleOrDefault();
```

Or if you want to do it in one statement:

```
UserOfferUsed objUserUsed = objEntity.UserOfferUseds
    .Where(TBL => TBL.UserID == UserID)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

If you look up functions like First / Single / Any / All, Linq functions that don't return a sequence but one element of the sequence, you'll find a version with a parameter and a parameterless version. The function with the parameter has the same effect as using Where with the parameter followed by the parameterless function:

```
var result = SomeSequence.Last( x => SomeFunction(x))
```

returns the same item of the sequence as:

```
var result = SomeSequence.Where( x => SomeFunction(x)).Last();
```